# Deploying EJB app on Heroku

Tags: heroku, ejb

I'm new to Heroku PaaS and I have spent sometime recently exploring how to deploy Java apps on Heroku. I was able to deploy simple Java apps and Spring apps as well.
However, I have an app which has EJB components in it.
My question is - Can EJB 2/3 apps be deployed on Heroku...if yes, where can I find more info about it. (I tried to look for it but couldn't find anything useful).
Any pointers would be really helpful.

Comment: I'm too interested. I'm now trying to push a simplest RMI Bean to Heroku. Will inform of any findings.

Comment: It seems impossible - at least for now. The reason: EJB Beans remoting is implemented with Java RMI. That's a binary protocol, i.e. not based on HTTP which Heroku could interface with. If I understand correctly, Heroku supports only one HTTP port, on which the application is supposed to bind. It is passed to the process as $PORT environment variable. The host proxy.heroku.com then passes all requests. Since RMI is binary based, I believe it can't be made to work with the infrastructure. It might be possible to achieve remoting with Spring and some HTTP based protocol. That's my next attempt.